# Skipping blank lines when reading line delimited list of strings

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to parse a simple text file using boost::spirit. The text file is a line delimited list of strings. I can get it to mostly work, except for when it comes to blank lines, which I would like to skip.

I've tried several approaches, but I either stop parsing at the blank line, or I get the blank line included in my results.

Is there a way to tell my grammar to skip blank lines?

### code

```
std::ifstream ifs("one.txt");
ifs >> std::noskipws;

std::vector< std::string > people;

if (parse(
     istream_iterator(ifs),
     istream_iterator(),
     *(as_string[+print >> (eol | eoi)]),
     people))
{
  std::cout << "Size = " << people.size() << std::endl;

  for (auto person : people)
  {
     std::cout << person << std::endl;
  }
}
```

### one.txt

```
Sally
Joe
Frank
Mary Ann

Bob
```

### What I Get

```
Sally
Joe
Frank
Mary Ann
```

### What I Want to Get

```
Sally
Joe
Frank
Mary Ann
Bob
```

**Bonus**: Can I strip leading or trailing spaces from the lines in the grammar at the same time? I need to keep the space in Mary Ann of course.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669287/how-to-parse-entries-followed-by-semicolon-or-newline-boostspirit can help you little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (qi::phrase_parse(
            first, last,
            -qi::as_string[qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)]] % qi::eol,
            qi::blank,
            people))
```

I'll refer to **[Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)** for more background. Quick notes:

```
if (qi::phrase_parse(
//      ^ ----- use a skipper to parse phrases whith a skipper (`qi::blank` here)
            first, last,
            -qi::as_string[qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_ - qi::eol)]] % qi::eol,
//          |                  |      |                          ^---- 1.
//          +---- 2.           |      +---- 4.
//       5. ----v       3. ----+      
            qi::blank,
            people))
```

1. match list of items separated by newlines
2. '-' makes the item optional (ignoring blank lines)
3. `lexeme` includes whitespace inside the subexpression (but it does still pre-skip, so lines with only whitespace count as empty lines; use `no_skip` if you don't want preskip to happen)
4. `+` requires at least 1 match, so empty names are not considered a name
5. the `blank` skipper skips whitespaces, but not newlines; this is because newlines are significant to your grammar. Also note that the `lexeme` still keeps the internal whitespace

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e22938e9a9a3ec3)</kbd>**

**UPDATE** In response to the comment, the added complexity was due to skipping whitespace. If you are happy trimming whitespace after the fact, by all means, use

```
if (parse(first, last, - as_string[+(char_ - eol)] % eol, people))
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f6d5602d00c68e4)** as well

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I'm trying to write up an article for my group at work about how they easy boost::spirit is to use, and that it isn't just for complicated formats.

This might scare them away. Is there no way to accomplish the same thing without having to introduce skippers?

Comment: @AaronWright exactly what part is complex? Or at least, which part is more complex than your sample? I mean, your sample just did less (too little?). If the schematic with notes looks complicating, look back to the original line of code. It's not inherently much more complex than, say, EBNF IYAM

Comment: I find the idea of introducing a skipper, just to defeat the skipper in the grammar, to be more complicated than I was hoping. I suppose it is true that if I want more functionality, I'm going to need more complexity.

Comment: @AaronWright By all mean, don't introduce a skipper and just trim the whitespace. I was being Spirit-y in my solution.

Comment: Anyways, in the _spirit_ of small examples, I give you a [small HTTP response headers parsing callback](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8989134/) and ditto [query parameter parsing function](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8989173/) and a [ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8989209/). I would /not/ enjoy writing and testing these without the composable parser primitives from Spirit

Comment: I've updated the answer with the skipper-less approach (**[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f6d5602d00c68e4)**). I think the point I'd drive home when plugging Spirit would be **not** how "easy" it is, but how productive this power tool can be. Especially when you need genericity.

Comment: I can't argue with that. I'll remember that when writting my article. This is one of the first examples, so I wanted to build up functionality, from the simpliest grammar that'll read the simpliest file, and then add features such as blank lines, etc. Kind of ease them into it. Thanks for the help.